# Clio Api v4 - from/to filters on Calendar Entries?

Tags: clio-api

I cannot get `from` and `to` filters working for calendar entries.

E.g. this gives me all entries for the calendar (including those from 2017):

`https://app.clio.com/api/v4/calendar_entries?calendar_id=12345&from=2018-04-15T02%3A09%3A39Z&fields=id%2C+etag%2C+calendar_owner%2C+start_at%2C+end_at%2C+all_day`

This looks like correct ISO 8601 to me, I also tried different formats (including non url-encoded versions) without any luck.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so format was actually not ISO8601. Due to PHP bug it formats date like this:

`2018-05-03T05:39:32+0000` but should like this: `2018-05-03T05:39:32+00:00`.

I changed `DateTime::ISO8601` to `DateTime::ATOM` format.